# Javascript Huffman Decoder/Translate method was working earlier but is now causing NullPointerException

Tags: java, decoding, huffman-code

I have been working on a HuffmanCode program and I thought I had finished it this morning. However, I have randomly started to get a `NullPointerException` even though it was working perfectly earlier today. Below is the method that is causing the problems: (port = left side of tree, star = right side of tree)

```
public void translate(BitInputStream input, PrintStream output) {
  HuffmanNode tempRootRef = huffmanRootRef;
  while(input.hasNextBit() || (tempRootRef.port == null && tempRootRef.star == null)) {
     if(tempRootRef.port == null && tempRootRef.star == null) {
        output.write(tempRootRef.charValue);
        tempRootRef = huffmanRootRef;
     } else if (input.nextBit() == 0){
        tempRootRef = tempRootRef.port;
     } else {
        tempRootRef = tempRootRef.star;
     }
  }
}
```

I am getting the `NullPointerException` on the first if statement:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at HuffmanCode.translate(HuffmanCode.java:118)
at HuffmanCompressor.decompress(HuffmanCompressor.java:115)
at HuffmanCompressor.main(HuffmanCompressor.java:178)
```

I tried reviewing answers to similar issues but I had trouble understanding them.

Comment: please locate line 118 in the code above.

Comment: Which line is 118? That's where the exception happens. Did you change your code or your input?

Comment: Line 118 is: if(tempRootRef.port == null && tempRootRef.star == null) {

Comment: The only thing that changed from earlier today was that I added comments to my methods. None of the code was altered and I am using the same input as before.

Comment: That can for instance happen if `huffmanRootRef` is null. Or at some point during the iteration either `tempRootRef.port` or `tempRootRef.star` is null and their value is assigned to `tempRootRef`. It may sound dumb, but sure you didn't comment anything necessary out while adding the comments? From the given code, there is no way anyone can locate the source of your exception, because it most certainly is an error while generating the data structures you are using here.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that huffmanRootRef has a non-null value, then a NPE in that line means that `input.hasNextBit()` returned `true`, but `tmpRootRef` is `null`.

I suggest tracing through your code (either in a debugger or with a couple of print statements) to watch the values as it executes.